# Timed player collision

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to make the player loose one heart then cool down for a second after being hit. For an example

```
if(a.overlaps(b)) {
p.health--;
}
```

would lower the health while being touched. In my old game I used a thread algorithm to wait a second, but that took a while. Besides doing some kind of complicated timer method, what can I do to keep to the player hit one at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the player a number in their class called `hitCountdown` or something. Every time they are hit, set that number to the amount of time you want to give the player to escape. Then, where you update the player, decrement the countdown

```
if(hitCountdown > 0) hitCountdown--;
```

Now, when you hit the player and damage him, write this:

```
if(a.overlaps(b)) {
    //if it has been a while since we got hit
    if(hitCountdown <= 0){
        p.health--;
    }
}
```